# Java best practice for avoiding delimiter collisions?

Tags: java, parsing, collision, delimiter

I have a number of Strings that I have to store in a DB that I'd like to split using String.split method later.  However, I'm concerned about delimiter collisions since at least one field could contain any character and the number of fields may vary.
I was thinking of using just a delimiter with an improbable set of characters. But I'm not sure if it is appropiate.

are there any other tricks you can think of?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

Don't store strings in the database that you're going to split.  If you have a 1:N relationship, model it with a database table that has a column with a unique key on the 1 side, and a second free-form column for the N side.

If nothing will convince you not to shove lists into DB columns, then maybe use an [integrity constraint](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96590/adg05itg.htm) to make sure that the values in the column have the expected format.

Comment: It depends on a task but generally yes, any non DB-style decision applied to a DB will likely create problems in future: e.g. upgrading a schema might turn out not to be easy enough.

Answer (score 2):

The same technique is used in XML with CDATA sections.  If you are creating your strings yourself, you can do some escaping before concatenating them.  You could pick delimiter characters  from some long dead (or not yet alive) language as delimiters - like klingon, cuneiform or phoenician.

Pick what you like: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

Comment: So you're saying that Klingon is... not _yet_ alive? Sorry, couldn't resist that one ;-)

Comment: ... damn, now I have to watch my back for big guys in riveted leather clothes wielding strange blades ;)

Comment: I like the idea of obscure delimiters, but I do feel the need to mention that storing pre-escaped values in a database is usually bad practice. You may be the sole publisher and consumer of the data, but who knows what will change in the future - and they will then have to work around your current escaped model. Storing raw data, and processing once extracted is best practice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use approach which is used in CSV (but not only): the string is wrapped into double quotas. Comma is obviously a delimiter. Then (some excerpts):

- Fields with embedded commas must be enclosed within double-quote
  characters.
- Fields with embedded double-quote characters must be enclosed within
  double-quote characters, and each of the embedded double-quote
  characters must be represented by a pair of double-quote characters.
- etc...

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values for more details.

CSV also supports line breaks and everything else as well, I guess. So I would use it (or simplified version, if possible) in this case - store a whole string array in CSV format. Then parse it using one of existing parsers.

Answer (score 0):

From the ASCII table use the record separator !E in Hexadecimal.   You will not be using 1E in any other context.